# ejs includes header but in some page don't load image

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

[Folder list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w5MY.png)

Hi, I'm new to node, express and ejs; this is a folder list of my project and for some reason when I include the header and footer on `home.ejs`, I can see the image on the `navbar`, but if I do the same in `terms-condition.ejs`, node load the page correctly with the `footer` and the `navbar`, but the `logo-image` isn't shown in the page.
The only difference between `home.ejs` and `terms-condition.ejs` is that the last one is in a subfolder of `/views`.

index.ejs

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/legal/terms-condition", function(req, res) {
    res.render("legal/terms-condition");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

home.ejs

```
<%- include("common/header") -%>

<div class="box">
    <a href="./legal/terms-condition">Terms and Condition</a>
</div>

<%- include("common/footer") -%>
```

terms-condition.ejs

```
<%- include("../common/header") -%>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h1>This is a sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <p>Why ejs not load the logo in the navbar?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<%- include("../common/footer") -%>
```

[here](https://github.com/Andrea-Agosta/ejs-include-img-issue) the link to my project on GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the `images/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg` with `/` i.g. `/images/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg`. In your code, did you notice that the `styles.css` loading correctly because you've prefix it with `/`.

You're facing this issue because the file `terms-condition.ejs` is within a folder whereas `home.ejs` not.

P.S. You should always put `node_modules` in `.gitignore` file.